# Convert python API example to PHP

Tags: php, python, api, rest, curl

I need to connect to a RESTful API. The only example the company gave me to connect to their API is a example in Python. I do not understand the language but am comfortable with PHP. Is there a way I can do this with cuRL and/or PHP?

Here is the example in Python:

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import datetime as dt
import simplejson as json
import sys


tech_prefix = '' #the Account Tech Prefix
secret_key = '' #the API Key


#creating URI info
t = dt.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)
timestamp = t.isoformat()
url_scheme = 'https'
net_location = 'api.thesite.com'
path = '/v1/available-tns/npas/'
method = 'GET'
ordered_query_params = ''
body = ''
body_md5 = ''
canonical_uri = url_scheme + "://" + net_location + path + "\n" + ordered_query_params
tokens = (
    timestamp,
    method,
    body_md5,
    canonical_uri
    )
message_string = u'\n'.join(tokens).encode('utf-8')
signature = hmac.new(secret_key, message_string, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()

headers = {'X-Timestamp':timestamp}
request_url = url_scheme + '://' + net_location + path + '?' + ordered_query_params #    append ordered query params here
request = requests.get(request_url,auth=(tech_prefix,signature),headers=headers)
print request
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this in PHP.  This python code doesn't use any special python libraries; it's just sending an HTTP request with specific headers and specific auth info.  Actually translating this code from python into PHP is outside the scope of a typical StackOverflow answer, though.

Comment: +1 For making sure it was possible, but not doing it.

Comment: Thanks, I use curl often but with this APIs auth needing to timestamp and hash the api key sending back a response code, Im lost. I guess I do need this code converted to php or a curl example from the basis of this code.

Answer (score 0):

First the "imports" are just external libraries, PHP has them built in. Everything up to token is just variables. The date and time methods all have similar functions in PHP. Then the "token" is just an array. Then "message_string" has a "join" and "encode" methods which are similar to what you would find in Javascript. The "signature" is a bit confusing but its basically doing an encryption and PHP has similar functions. Python is well documented so look up the functions for Python and then you should be able to figure out which PHP function is similar. After "signature" it is just assembling all the variables into the HTTP request and sending it.

Python, and PHP (and javascript) are C based languages. If you are good with one you can figure out the other, as long as you have good reference material. And as noted Python is well documented, so a Google search for the Python methods or functions should turn up the info you need to find its PHP equivalent.

API's are never fun to work with, but they are not impossible. Most of them break down to being just an HTTP request you have to assemble, and then dissecting the response. A little trick, sometimes you can find in the API's documentation, or on their forums (if they have them) or maybe tech support will send you, an example of what the HTTP request should look like. Then you can just build it in PHP.

As a closing note, it is good to learn how to convert between languages. It sounds like this is your first experience with it but most web developers run into this regularly and for a variety of different languages (python, c++, asp, ruby, ect). Based on what I have ran into in the past, yours is a fairly simple one to convert. I would loved to have had  that as the example for the last API I had to work with.